# Extraction of coefficient from Generating Function

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, generating-functions

Determine the coefficient of $~x ^ {12}~$ in:

$(1+^2+^4+^6+^8+^{10}+^{12})(1+^4+^8+^{12})(1+^6+^{12})(1+^8)(1+^{10})(1+^{12})$

How to proceed with the resolution of this type of question when there is the product of more than two functions?

Comment: The coefficient will be the coefficient of $x^{12}$ in

$y^{-1}$

where

$$y=(1-x^2)(1-x^4)(1-x^6)(1-x^8)(1-x^{10})(1-x^{12})$$

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coefficient of $x^{12}$ is equal to the  number of partitions of $12$ in which all summands are even.

Given a partition of $12$ in which all summands are even we can divide each summand by $2$ to get a partition of $6$. And given a partition of $6$ we can find a partition of $12$ with even summands by doubling each summand. So there is a one-to-one correspondence between the partitions of $12$ in which all summands are even and the partitions of $6$.

Therefore the coefficient of $x^{12}$ is equal to the  number of partitions of $6$.

Comment: Really cool reasoning. Thank you very much. :)